# std::equal_range possible implementation

Tags: c++, stl

The [std::equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) shows a possible implementation for `std::equal_range`:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
std::pair<ForwardIt, ForwardIt> 
    equal_range(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::lower_bound(first, last, value),
                          std::upper_bound(first, last, value));
}
```

Is there a specific reason to start with `first` again in `std::upper_bound` instead of using the result of `std::lower_bound` ?

For example:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
std::pair<ForwardIt, ForwardIt> 
    equal_range(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    ForwardIt lower = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
    return std::make_pair(lower, std::upper_bound(lower, last, value));
}
```

It seems to me excessive to check the range [first, lower) again, since `upper` should be in another part, anyway.

I understand that [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) provides the simplest example to explain the idea behind the algorithm, not the optimized version which could be complex. My question is different. May I use my optimization or I miss some corner point? Like "consider what your implementation would do on empty array or if the range is missing, etc.".

Do I miss something and this simple optimization could be risky?

I am not trying to achieve the best performance (like in the [libstdc++ implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/54ee8abfe62dc97f725843f58fe896eebcc52db0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L2118)),
I am just curious if this simple optimization is safe.

**Update**

It is a great suggestion from *Marshall Clow* in comments to use the tests from [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/test/std/algorithms/alg.sorting/alg.binary.search/equal.range/equal_range.pass.cpp) library.

Comment: I believe it should be safe, yes.

Comment: cppreference has just provided a one liner. You don't even need `make_pair` in modern C++: a pair of curly braces is all you need:`return {lower,whatever};`

Comment: @Red.Wave, thanks I am aware and use it in my code. I just used the original from cppreference and did my best to change as little code as possible to keep the idea visible. As I stressed in my question, my concern was not imaginary "inefficiency" of the cppreference code, by only the correctness of mine change. I wasn't sure that I didn't miss something with this change. Some kind of the corner case. The question was caused by much more complex piece of code where I forced to do such a trick and can't use std::equal_range.

Comment: Write some tests. :-). Convince yourself that your implementation works at least as well as the one from CppReference.

Comment: @MarshallClow, per my experience, this approach doesn't work at all. When the same person writes the code and tests it, they make the same wrong assumptions both in the code and tests. So, need a volunteer to write one to have at least one other opinion and pair of eyes. Can I consider your step in as such a call? :)

Comment: Take the `equal_range` tests from libc++ :-)

Comment: My experience has not matched yours.  I have written large amounts of c++ code (Boost, libc++, and proprietary code) and pretty much always written my own tests.  I think I've been successful at that.

Comment: @MarshallClow, writing large amount of code you lost human sense of humor :) Kidding again, BTW. It was a joke in style "your idea, your work". For sure, you are correct here, for such technical code self-testing works mostly fine. And basic testing must be done the the developer. But in domain areas I always put different people to write code and tests, since this is mostly about correct mapping of requirements to the code. I am in two minds about "technical" code, still. I will refer to an example in the next post. Thank you for the hint with libc++ tests, it helps!

Comment: @MarshallClow, I am in two minds about writing the tests by the same developer even for "technical" code because of the same wrong assumptions in the code and tests. And the recent example for this is Microsoft's XMMath's `BoundingSphere::CreateFromPoints` which is still in repo with error missed by too simple test. Namely, if you provide axes aligned zero-centered box where all max's are equal and all min's are equal, it simply doesn't work. I am in two minds if this could be missed by another developer who would have written the tests.