# Using structured binding declaration for unpacking the result of std::equal_range

Tags: c++, stl

Because of readability concerns I avoid usage of [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) for complex code to keep variables names meaningful.

Taking into account that [std::equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) returns the `std::pair` of iterators, is it effective and safe to use [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to unpack the iterators in this way:

Instead of

```
auto it_lower = std::lower_bound(my_array.begin(), my_array.end(), val, comparator);
auto it_upper = std::upper_bound(my_array.begin(), my_array.end(), val, comparator);
```

use

```
auto [it_lower, it_upper] = std::equal_range(my_array.begin(), my_array.end(), val, comparator);
```

approach?

Forgetting about possible different implementation of `equal_range` and `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` pair (different performance, etc.) and focusing on the structured bundling usage only, is this equal both from terms of representation in compiled code and performance? I am not asking what the compiler will do. My question is just, if I correctly use the tool and could I expect the similar results? Or there are some difference or even worse, traps?

Do I miss something or this is perfectly fine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cpp
auto [it_lower, it_upper] = std::equal_range(...
```

This is perfectly safe, effective and is the recommended approach.

Compared to searching the full range for `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` like you showed, it also has the potential of being more effective.

---

To explain the last statement, your search for the upper bound includes the range `[my_array.begin(), it_lower)` which in most circumstances will cause more comparisons than necessary.

The search for the upper bound should use `it_lower` as the *first* iterator to exclude the range already excluded by `std::lower_bound`:

```cpp
auto it_lower = std::lower_bound(my_array.begin(), my_array.end(), val, comparator);
auto it_upper = std::upper_bound(it_lower, my_array.end(), val, comparator);
//                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you. One clarification, am I right that this will have initialization semantic like first code snippet, not assignment? In this simple case this is irrelevant and could be left up to compiler even in case of assignment, of course. But in more tricky case it would be nice to be sure that this is initialization, not assignment.

Comment: @DamirTenishev It's initialization - and also, iterators are supposed to be lightweight so even if they were left uninitialized and then move assigned, it would be effective

Comment: On your comment on the using the `it_lower` as possible optimization, you will be laughing, but just an hour before this question, I posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461666/stdequal-range-possible-implementation, so I am aware of this. Like on en.cppreference.com, my idea was to provide the simplest code to avoid distracting from the main topic of the question. Anyway, thank you for this addition, this gives me double confidence in this simple optimization.